# recursive Bounded knapsack algorithm

Tags: r, algorithm, recursion, knapsack-problem

I am struggling with translating the dynamic programming recursive knapsack problem 0-1 to a dynamic bounded recursive knapsack.
The formula i am currently using in R is:

```
F(i,k)=max(v[i]+F(i-1, k-w[i]), F(i-1, k))
```

so now I am wondering what this function would become for a bounded dynamic knapsack problem

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The simplest modification - make needed quantity of repeated elements

```
 {3x1,2x5}=>{1,1,1,5,5}
```

Another approach - create array/vector with numbers of copies and use it in recursive calls to check only entries with non-zero copy counts